# Is grep available in github mac app?

Tags: git, macos, github

Is it possible to grep from within the github mac app (mac.github.com) ?

This would be a very useful feature.

Comment: (1) It would be sensible to give a link to the code/project on GitHub. (2) Have you taken a look at the code? (3) What do you mean by 'grep from within'?  The question is somewhat ambiguous, perhaps more so because I don't know what facilities the 'github mac app' provides in the first place.

Comment: I think OP means the official Github for Mac app https://mac.github.com/

You can certainly ⌘F

Answer (score 1):

[`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) is a unix command and can be used in your entire file system.

So, if you want to do "grep" in your project, just go to the directory and try the following command:

```
ls | grep "your pattern"
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. Also the use of `ls` for grepping is questionable - this will try to match the pattern in the list of filenames, not in the files themselves...